# LinearLayout not centering vertically

Tags: android, android-layout

My linearlayout wont align vertically

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    android:gravity="center"

    android:background="#000050"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:id="@+id/pager"
>   
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pagenum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help me? The buttons are chilling at the top of the linear layout and theres like a 4dp or so gap from the bottom

Comment: android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" is part of RelativeLayout and not part of LinearLayout unless this is for ICS which I do not have right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if this is what you want..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#000050"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Back" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pagenum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the gap is part of the button border and looks like you can not get rid of them. Notice that the default background also provides spacing on the right side so that next widget does not appear sticking to it.

Since you are trying to position them on a 50dp height, the gap stands out, if those buttons are at the bottom of the screen then maybe the gap might be the right thing for your app design as well.

If you really want to get rid of them they you will have to provide a custom background to the widgets.